# firebase serve and debugging functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-functions

I ran

> firebase serve --only-functions

Then ran

> functions inspect addMessage

So I could debug the addMessage function. Debugging however did not work.

Running

> firebase deploy addMessage --trigger-http
>    firebase inspect addMessage

Did work and allow me to debug but it doesn't seem to support hot reloading.

Is it possible to have hot reloading and debugging working at the same time?

My index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    // Grab the text parameter.
    const original = "123";//req.query.text;
    // Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase Admin SDK.
    return admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original}).then((snapshot) => {
      // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
      return res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref.toString());
    });
  });
```

Comment: If the reload kills the emulator process, probably not.  You'll need to attach to the replacement process.

Comment: @DougStevenson Upon further investigation it looks like using firebase serve does not allow me to debug even if I run the inspect addMessage command aftewrards, I have to do a firebase deploy addMessage --trigger-http followed by functions inspect addMessage to have debugging working.

Is it possible to run firebase serve and debug firebase functions locally?

Comment: No, background functions won't fire locally.  You can debug http functions, though.

Comment: Well i tried firebase serve --only functions and debugging my addMessage function but the breakpoints did not hit  :-/

Comment: @tweetypi I have the same problem. You find solution?

Comment: @tweetypi did you get this working?

Answer (score 3):

try: `ndb firebase serve`

debugger breakpoints are hit with stack traces visible, note it's a little slow so give the debugger time to instrument the child processes

Additionally I was able to debug cloud functions in isolation using (caps for removed values):

`GCLOUD_PROJECT=THE-FIREBASE-PROJECT node --inspect-brk /path/to/functions-framework --target FUNCTION-NAME --port=5000`

where functions-framework simply expands to the full path for the installed functions-framework (global in my case) from the working directory where the index.js file is for the target functions.

Alternately when or where the FIREBASE_CONFIG is needed try this format adjusted to fit:
`FIREBASE_CONFIG="{\"databaseURL\":\"https://YOUR-FIREBASE-PROJECT.firebaseio.com\",\"storageBucket\":\"YOUR-FIREBASE-PROJECT.appspot.com\",\"projectId\":\"YOUR-FIREBASE-PROJECT\"}`

- https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/ndb
- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/functions-framework
- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/issues/15

Answer (score 1):

As of firebase-tools v7.11.0, the Firebase emulator now supports attaching a debugger with the `--inspect-functions` option. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61975914/925478) shows WebStorm-specific instructions that can be easily adapted to other debuggers.