# How to debug firebase cloud functions in WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, firebase, debugging, google-cloud-functions, webstorm

I've started a firebase cloud functions project and want to know how i can get the debugging within the WebStorm IDE running?

I've read that i can archive my goal using @google-cloud/functions-emulator.
Therefore I installed it and followed this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/emulator)

After running `functions inspect myFunction`, I got following output.

```
Warning: You're using Node.js v10.6.0 but the Google Cloud Functions runtime is only available in Node.js 6 and Node.js 8. Therefore, results from running emulated functions may not match production behavior.
Debugger for app listening on port 9229.
```

I assume debugging should work now. Open myFunction in the browser (e. g. http://localhost:8010/my-project/us-central1/myFunction/) works fine.

Now I'm struggling. What do I have to do to connect the IDE to the debugger or the debugger to the IDE? I have no clue how debugging works.

Expected result: I want to open the function in Chrome Browser following by pausing on the break points in the WebStorm IDE.

Thanks for helping in advance ;)

Comment: I'd suggest trying [Attach to Node.js/Chrome](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.3/run-debug-configuration-node-js-remote-debug.html) run configuration: add breakpoints, start the emulator with `functions inspect`, in run configuration set *port* to `9229`, debug...

Comment: thanks! This works fine ;)

Comment: see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/issues/15 as well as related answer for debugging firebase functions at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56715735/965666 Hope this allows you to answer the question directly.

Answer (score 24):

As of [firebase-tools v7.11.0](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v7.11.0), the Firebase emulator now supports attaching a debugger with the `--inspect-functions` option. This allows you to use WebStorm to debug locally-running firebase functions while using the rest of the (much improved) emulator tools.

First make sure you have the necessary `firebase-tools`:

```
$ npm install firebase-tools@latest
```

Now you can start your functions in the Firebase emulator from your project directory:

```
$ firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions
```

The output will show something like:

```
$ firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions, hosting
⚠  functions: You are running the functions emulator in debug mode (port=9229). This means that functions will execute in sequence rather than in parallel.
✔  functions: Using node@10 from host.
```

Note the "port=9229" in the output above. This is the port to which we're going to tell WebStorm to attach.

Open your project in WebStorm, then:

1. select **Run | Edit Configurations...**
2. In the "Run/Debug Configurations" window, click the "+" button and select "Attach to Nodejs/chrome" option.

[image: Attach]

3. Select your new configuration, and configure it to attach to the port shown in the output above (9229 in my case):

[image]

4. Click **Apply** and **OK**. Your configuration is saved.

From the main WebStorm menu, you can now select **Run | Debug...** and select your new configuration. WebStorm will attach to the process hosting your functions, and you can use debug features (breakpoints, etc.) just like a normal debug session from within WebStorm.

Comment: I followed these steps now I always get WebSockets request was expected. And the debugger in webstorm fails telling me invalid response from the remote host. IS there a step I missed?

Comment: @RossRawlins only thing I can think is that `firebase emulators:start` either didn't start, or the port used is different and doesn't match what you put into WebStorm. I'd suggest posting a new question with your specific steps and error message if you're still having trouble.

Comment: I have create a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63156113/firebase-emulator-inspect-function-failing-to-run. Please can you have a look when you have a chance.

Comment: I followed all the steps but my script doesn't actually stop on breakpoints. How can I debug this issue? I'm on firebase tools 9+

Comment: `Is there a way to select the debug port?` `Yes, firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions 10001` though you need to ensure that firebase respects this port, if its taken it will try use the default 9229 again

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE 2020:**

As of [firebase-tools v7.11.0](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v7.11.0) the Firebase emulator allows debugging of hosted functions with the `--inspect-functions` flag. This has many advantages over using [functions-framework](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/functions-framework) as described below. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61975914/925478) for details.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Configuring WebStorm to debug a Firebase function can be confusing because there are a couple of [different ways](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/master/docs/debugging.md) to run Firebase functions locally.

Here's what works for me:

1. `npm install --save-dev @google-cloud/functions-framework`
2. In WebStorm create a `Node.js` debug configuration

   - Run | Edit Configurations... | + | Node.js
3. Name it as you please (eg, "Debug Function").
4. In the "JavaScript file:" box, specify: `node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/index.js`
5. In "Application Parameters", specify `--target=<your-function-name>`
6. Click OK

It should look something like this:
[image]

(In my example, I'm also specifying the `--port` switch to set the port the function will listen on).

After that, running `Run | Debug | Debug Function` from the WebStorm menu will load up your function and hit any breakpoints you've set.

Comment: doesnt FB come with a shell you can hook into without install FF?

Comment: So how does that listen to the actual Firebase database? Ie if I add a user then I want to debug this function: 
https://github.com/QuantumInformation/svelte-fullstack-starter/blob/master/firebase_specific/functions/src/index.ts#L35

How is that possible locally?

Comment: @Nikos if you want to connect to live database resources (or other Firebase/GCP resources), you need to set up your local environment to use a service account associated with your (production) Firebase instance. I do this regularly for non-Firebase GCP projects, but haven't done it with Firebase, but I suspect it should all work the same way. See e.g. https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk

Comment: I did the above but I'm having problems: No Firebase ID token was passed as a Bearer token in the Authorization header. Make sure you authorize your request by providing the following HTTP header: Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token> or by passing a "__session" cookie. I can run my code with no error when I do npm run serve.

Comment: @Nikos it does now (and maybe when you asked the question)! The debug/emulator support is much improved from the time this question was originally answered. I added https://stackoverflow.com/a/61975914/925478 with what I understand to be the latest-and-greatest.

Comment: Thanks I am now using this **firebase emulators:start --only functions --inspect-functions** however I get Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5002/svelte-fullstack-starter/us-central1/listUsers' from origin 'http://localhost:5001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Answer (score 4):

## 1. Configuration

Add this `npm run` script to `package.json`:

`"dev": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions --inspect-functions 10001 & tsc --watch"`

- This will build and run the functions emulator
- this will recompile TypeScript files to JavaScript when they are saved, so that the Firebase emulator can reload them while running.
- If you don't use TypeScript, remove `& tsc --watch` from above
- Allows a debugger to connect at port 10001 (you can update this number)

You can create a WebStorm run configuration for this:

[image: WebStorm run config - npm run dev]

Then, create a debug configuration for Firebase functions, telling WebStorm to connect to the port number you specified earlier (10001):

[image: Debug Firebase functions]

## 2. How to launch

1. Run `npm run dev` in a terminal, or launch from WebStorm the `npm dev` configuration you've created bove.

   You'll need to launch this using WebStorm or manually before the next step, every time, unless you use compound run configurations (see last section)
2. Connect WebStorm's debugger to the Firebase emulator you launched at the previous step, by running the <kbd>Debug Firebase functions</kbd> configuration from the dropdown:

   [image: Launched 'Debug Firebase functions']

To test the debugger, make a `curl` call to your Firebase function.

## Extra tip: compound run configurations

You can create a `Compound` run configuration, which starts all the things you might need. In this case you'd have the `npm dev` command, and the `Debug Firebase functions` command:

[image: WebStorm compound run configuration]