# "array.forEach is not a fuction" after firebase deploy but works on firebase serve

Tags: node.js, firebase, deployment, google-cloud-functions

After deployment my array does not seem to be defined and I get a "forEach is not a function" error:

```
   textPayload: "TypeError: currencies.forEach is not a function
    at currenciesMenuConfiguration (/srv/menu/currencies-menu.js:22:16)
```

Here's the code for the currencies array:

```
    async function currenciesMenuConfiguration() {
    currencies = await getCol("currencies")
    currencies.forEach(element => {
        return currenciesList[element[Object.keys(element)].id] = element[Object.keys(element)].current
    });
}
```

This gets called right after being defined with `currenciesMenuConfiguration()`

getCol is defined as:

```
// Get all documents in collection from Firestore
async function getCol(colName) {
  return fs.collection(colName).get()
  .then(res => {
    return res.docs.map(doc => {
      var rObj = {};
      rObj[doc.id] = doc.data();
      return rObj;
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return `Error getting collection: ${err}`;
  });  
}
```

As mentioned on firebase serve locally this works without an issue. After deployment, I get this error. Am I missing something about asynchronous code in the cloud?

Also, any tips on how I would go about debugging this myself would be much appreciated. #BeginngersLife.

// I have checked the questions on so about firebase serve vs deployment but they mostly deal with issues around deployment or don't address the issue I am facing. One question that might help me get further in this is: [firebase serve and debugging functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493498/firebase-serve-and-debugging-functions).

Comment: You might want to log what you get back from `getCol("currencies")`, since it doesn't seem to be what you expect.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the suggestion. I did log the output during development and forgot about it. Thanks! I do indeed return an object. Not an array.

Comment: OK. I'm going to mark this question as a typo in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comment below question: I did indeed not return an array but an object. Closing. Thanks for the hint @Frank van Puffelen.