# Debugging Firebase functions locally (node.js)

Tags: debugging, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

see below my code is very simple....it listens to a change on a database field in realtime-database.

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

exports.onActiveUpdate = functions.database
  .ref("/profiles/users/{userId}/active")
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      //code here
      
    return true;
  });
```

I've tried to debug code locally with the following commands

```
firebase serve --only functions
firebase serve
firebase emulators:start
```

I always get the same message...

```
+  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
i  functions: Watching "C:\code\rn\xs\fb_functions\functions" for Cloud Functions...
i  functions[onActiveUpdate]: function ignored because the database emulator does not exist or is not running.
+  All emulators started, it is now safe to connect.
```

But then when I go to localhost:5001....all I see is a blank page with with `{"status":"alive"}` at the top.

Is this correct behavior?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Functions debugging in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920014/functions-debugging-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 9):

You can run the emulator in inspect mode by running :

```
firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions
```

See what port it's listening to for debug (e.g. port 9229 ).
If you are using VSCode, create(or update) a **launch.json** inside **.vscode** subdirectory of your project with the following content:

```
   {
    "configurations": [
        {   "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Debug",
            "port": 9229
        }
     ]
   }
```

Then simply click on Debug icon in your VScode to connect to the running process.
Now put some breakpoints in your functions code and invoke them through browser.

Comment: Port 9229 is important. I first thought it was what my Emulators terminal was telling me (5001), but it is actually a separate port for debugging 9229.

Comment: What @SebastianPatten says is very important

You will see a message like:
`Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/....`
Find the port number there and use it in your debugger config

Comment: 9229 is your websocket port. 5001 is your HTTP port. Different ports for different protocols.

More context, 9229 is the Node.js inspector port https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/ndb to debug your **http** firebase functions.

Install it locally or globally and run your normal serve command with ndb:

`ndb yarn serve`

Comment: While it looks good, that is just a debugger, with nothing Firebase specific. How would one use it to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried firebase emulator suite and found it does enable [node.js Inspector](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector) and hence support step-by-step local debug nicely.

Assuming all your modules are good for emulator so we can focus on enabling local debug.

I choose MS Code as my Inspector Client.

- Execute `firebase emulators:start` and verify your function is working fine on local.
- Go to MS Code Run/Debug screen, select "add a configuration..." and select "{}Node.js: Attach to process" to create a new .vscode/launch.json. You will see the debug configuration with name of "Attach by Process ID" is generated.
- From MS Code Run/Debug screen, run this new "Attach by Process ID" debugger. You will be asked to choose a node process to attach the debugger.
- You should see 2 "functionsEmulatorRuntime" processes among all other node.js processes (1 for the functionsEmulator itself and another 1 for your function code). Try pick each of them and check if the debugger is able to pause on your break point.

Comment: This worked like a champ for me. Thanks, @Dery!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype?database=RTDB#start_the_database_and_cloud_functions_emulators), the command line for starting both the emulators for Cloud Functions and Realtime Database is this:

```
firebase emulators:start --only database,functions
```

Comment: ...when I try this I get a new error......"Not starting the database emulator, make sure you have run firebase init".  I definitely ran "firebase init functions" when I first created the project

Comment: Also run `firebase init database` to initialize the database product as well.

Comment: OK thats progress thanks - I now have functions emulator on port 5001 and database emulator on port 9000.  I want to set a breakpoint in my function so I can step through my code when the database update triggers it.  What URL do I go to, to debug?  Thanks

Comment: The emulator suite currently does not support step through debugging.  It's being worked on.

Comment: OK thats interesting.....so for now you just use the emulator for console output?  Can you tell me how I can run a function and view console output.  Sorry for all questions but I am a newbie at this

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Console log should appear just fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202227/discussion-between-james-murphy-and-doug-stevenson).

Answer (score 0):

Solution given by pref works. Below is my .vscode/launch.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {   "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Node.js-Debugger",
            "port": 9229
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is my firebase command.

```
$ firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions --import emulator_data --export-on-exit
```