# Debugging local firebase functions using VSCode - NodeJS version could not be determined?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-functions

When I run firebase serve in powershell and try to attach to it using visual studio code I get an error in VSCode saying:

> "Request 'evaluate' was cancelled because Node.js is unresponsive"

While the debug console outputs:

> Debugging with legacy protocol because Node.js version could not be
>   determined (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5001)

Here is my launch json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Debug Function",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 5001
      }
    ]
}
```

Something which might be relevant but I'm not sure as searching for it has given me conflicting results, when I run

```
firebase serve --only functions,hosting
```

I get an error in the console output saying:

> Warning: You're using Node.js v8.9.1 but Google Cloud Functions only
>   supports v6.11.5.

And if I use VSCode to try and attach using the above configuration I get the following error in debug console:

> Debugging with legacy protocol because Node.js version could not be
>   determined (Error: timeout)

Not sure how to deal with this

Comment: i am also facing similar issue. Did you get the resolution?

Comment: I switched to Azure.

Comment: This is actually a really decent answer on a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53981491/3853880