# Firebase: how to debug onCall functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using [Google Cloud Functions Emulator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator) for debugging locally my Firebase functions. 
Firebase recommend to use `functions.https.onCall` [functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) instead of  `functions.https.onRequest` for avoid using http calls directly. Instead Firebase recommend to use [Firebase Functions SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) for call such functions from code. 
For `functions.https.onRequest` I used `http-trigger` flag but how can I debug `onCall` functions ?

Comment: What is `http-trigger` and how did you use it? Are you asking if it's possible to test callable functions in the emulator?

Comment: @DougStevenson I mean command. This full command is: `functions deploy helloWorld --trigger-http`. But this is not working with onCall functions. So yes, the question is: how to test callable functions in the emulator?

Comment: I have no idea what that command is.  That doesn't looks like use of the Firebase CLI at all.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, because this is emulator command. Firebase official documentation refers to the emulator which I mentioned above: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator
Firebase refers to use `onCall` functions if I want to call them from web-SDK or any other platform SDK instead of  `onRequest`. But I can't find any example how to actually develop such functions due to missing any ability to debug.

Comment: There is currently no way to debug callables locally.  The team is working on that.  But I still don't understand what that command is.  It's not part of the docs you linked.  It sounds like you might be mixing up the Firebase CLI and gcloud.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ok, thanks. This is a command from README file in CloudFunctionsEmulator repository. I successfully using it for debug my cloud functions via `curl` or `postman` or smth like that

Comment: You should be able to use the Firebase CLI directly for local emulation.  You shouldn't have to invoke the emulator like that directly.

Comment: @neustart47 can you check my Answer and accept it if it solved your problem?

Comment: @ChadPavliska Hi, thanks for your answer, I will up vote it but still looking for a way to debug it the same as `onRequest` function via Google Cloud Functions Emulator.

Answer (score 6):

I found a way to run 'onCall' cloud functions locally and call them from a local client. I still haven't figured out how to attach a debugger but at least I can iterate faster and use console.log statements.

Use `firebase serve` to host the functions. Even though these are supposed to be for http requests I found that the the firebase clients have a property to override the host name for `onCall` functions. This takes care of authentication and passing in the right data and context objects for you.

**From Terminal in the root of your firebase project folder:**

`firebase serve`

You should get a successful result in the terminal window. Take the hostname and port number:

`✔  functions: helloWorld: http://localhost:5000/your-project-name/us-central1/helloWorld`

**iOS client:**

`Functions.functions().useFunctionsEmulator(origin: "http://localhost:5000")`

NOTE: you have to disable App Transport Security in iOS for this to work

NOTE: other clients probably have the same API.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `useFunctionsEmulator`. Have you figured out how to attach a debugger yet? I found this guide that might be useful but it assumes https request functions as well :/  https://medium.com/@mwebler/debugging-firebase-functions-with-vs-code-3afab528bb36

Comment: No, I never figured it out and haven't revisited since.