# How to change the firbase function from(functions.https.onRequest) to (functions.https.onCall)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i've already completed the firebase function that realized notification.

so i tried to change function Type , but fail.. how to change this code?

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onRequest((request,response)=>{

  const id = request.body.user_id;
  const pw = request.body.user_pw;
  const yourToken = request.body.yourToken;
  const myToken = request.body.myToken;

  var payload = {
    notification:{
      title : "notify",
      body : "suceess to send."
    },
    data:{
      title : "notify",
      body : "suceess to send.",
      user_id : id,
      user_pw : pw,
      myToken : myToken,
      yourToken : yourToken,
    }
  };
  
  response.send(admin.messaging().sendToDevice(yourToken, payload));
  
});
```

from this code to ..

```
exports.Notification = functions.https.onCall((data,context)=>{





 });
```

this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you will need to first understand the main differences between `onRequest()` (HTTPS-Express like) and `onCall()` (Callable) Firebase Functions.

From [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable):

> It's important to keep in mind that HTTPS callable functions are similar but not identical to HTTP functions. Callables have these key difference from HTTP functions:

> - With callables, Firebase Authentication and FCM tokens, when available, are automatically included in requests.
> - The functions.https.onCall trigger automatically deserializes the request body and validates auth tokens.

For a more exhaustive explanation, see [Are Callable Cloud Functions better than HTTP functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475667/are-callable-cloud-functions-better-than-http-functions/49476648#49476648)

This is some code, which is *untested*, that you can use to get started:

```
    exports.sendToDevice = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    
      // Data passed from the client using the Callable
      const id = data.user_id;
      const pw = data.user_pw;
      const yourToken = data.token;
      const myToken = data.myToken;

      var payload = {
        notification:{
           title : "notify",
           body : "suceess to send."
        },
        data:{
           title : "notify",
           body : "suceess to send.",
           user_id : id,
           user_pw : pw,
           myToken : myToken,
           yourToken : yourToken,
        }
      };

      return await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(yourToken, payload);
  );
```

Please note that `data` could contain the message text, while `context` parameters represent user auth information.

`context` contains metadata about the request such as uid and token, more information can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.callablecontext.html).

***Edited***:

Sample code to define `payload` can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-to-individual-devices). The `sendToDevice()` method can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#sendtodevice).

Comment: Oh I really appreciate your help. There was little reference. thanks  a lot!!

Comment: But there is some problem in (admin.messaging.MessagingPayload) . Because Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files. What can I do instead this code?

Comment: I just edited my answer and added more references to the documentation for the `sendToDevice()` method. I hope it helps.