# Java Callable Cloud Functions example

Tags: java, https, google-cloud-functions

I see many information on callable functions written using node.js , but none using java.

I see callable functions has many [features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49476648/13492963) [build](https://medium.com/wesionary-team/callable-function-how-to-write-and-deploy-a-callable-function-9eb8c109186e) in, e.g.

1. With callable functions, firebase authentication and FCM tokens are automatically included in requests when available.
2. Request body gets deserialized automatically and tokens are validated on functions.https.onCall trigger.

Is there a way to write callable functions using Java ? if yes any example code

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing#types_of_cloud_functions does not have infor on Callable Cloud Functions

Answer (score 0):

[HTTPS Callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) are a feature of Cloud Functions for Firebase, which [only supports Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_runtime_options), so there isn't currently a way to write Callables using Java.

If you'd like to be able to write Callables (and other function types) in Java with Cloud Functions for Firebase, please [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features). For now, a workaround might be to write a simple Node.js callable function that forwards relevant information to another, non-Firebase, Cloud Function written in Java via PubSub or HTTP.