# Firebase cloud functions SDK error while calling

Tags: python, reactjs, firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase cloud function written in Python called hello_world_fn:

```
from firebase_functions import https_fn
from firebase_admin import firestore
import google.cloud.firestore

@https_fn.on_request()
def hello_world_fn(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    return "hello world"
```

The React code in my Next JS project to run it is the following:

```
const functions = getFunctions()
const helloWorld = httpsCallable(functions, "hello_world_fn")
const result = await helloWorld({})
console.log(result)
```

I can run the cloud function perfectly fine from Postman, and the permission is set to allUsers on google cloud console, for testing purposes.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `Not working` is not a good problem description.

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing up [HTTP functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?gen=2nd) with [callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd).  They work differently, and you should review the documentation to understand the difference.  In python, callable functions are annotated with `@https_fn.on_call()` instead of the `@https_fn.on_request()` you have now.

Your client is trying to invoke a callable function, but your backend is defined as an HTTP function.  You're going to have to change one or the other so that they match.  If you want the client to continue to use a callable, then you're going to have to write a callable function on your backend as well.

See also:

- [Are Callable Cloud Functions better than HTTP functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475667/are-callable-cloud-functions-better-than-http-functions)