# Calling Firebase Function from Angular gives "bad request" error, but works fine called from URL

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am very new to Firebase Functions. I created a Function called getQuizById(). The function returns the Quiz in JSON format. If I call the function directly via a URL, it returns the JSON data as expected. e.g.:

https://us-central1-example-f1afa.cloudfunctions.net/getQuizById?id=ef8GwUuHt8X4XQJBIgZf

Since that is working, I need to call that same function from my Angular 17 app, here is the code I am using for that:

```
import { Functions, httpsCallable } from '@angular/fire/functions';

  private functions: Functions = inject(Functions);

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    // get the id fdrom the url
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    const getQuizById = httpsCallable(this.functions, 'getQuizById');

    getQuizById({ id: 'ef8GwUuHt8X4XQJBIgZf' }) // <- HARD CODED ID JUST FOR TESTING
      .then((result) => { // <- ERROR HERE
        console.log(result);
      });
  }
```

I took this code example straight from the docs on the Firebase website, so I assume I'm doing it correctly. Still, the Function itself is not receiving the passed in ID parameter, so it is failing with code 400 ("Quiz ID is required").

Here is the code from the Function itself, in case it helps.

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and triggers.
const { logger } = require("firebase-functions");
const { onRequest } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const { cors } = require("cors")({ origin: true });

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const { initializeApp, applicationDefault, cert } = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { getFirestore, Timestamp, FieldValue, Filter } = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

initializeApp();

const db = getFirestore();

exports.getQuizById = onRequest({ cors: true }, async (request, response) => {
    const quizId = request.query.id;

    if (!quizId) {
        response.status(400).send("Quiz ID is required");
        return;
    }

    try {
        const quizDocref = db.collection("quizzes").doc(quizId);
        const quizDoc = await quizDocref.get();

        if (!quizDoc.exists) {
            response.status(404).send("Quiz not found. ID: " + quizId);
            return;
        }

        response.status(200).json(quizDoc.data());
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error getting quiz document:", error);
        response.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up HTTP and callable type functions.  Your function is defined as an HTTP type function, but your client code is trying to invoke it as a callable type function.  That doesn't work at all, because callable type functions have a [very specific protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).  I suggest reading: [How do Callable Cloud Functions compare to HTTP functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475667/how-do-callable-cloud-functions-compare-to-http-functions)

If you want to invoke your HTTP function from your app, then just use a regular HTTP client, such as the [browser's fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

If you want to have a callable type function instead, then you'll have to define your cloud function differently using onCall instead of onRequest, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be correct. Since the CallableFunction seems more helpful than the HTTP call, I'd like to go that direction. I'm not sure why but I cannot seem to "reply to your reply" like I used to be able to do, so I'll open a new question as the code I re-wrote is not working.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but Stack Overflow has only ever allowed for a series of comments on an answer.  Commenting is essentially replying, which you just did.  Typically you @-mention the person to ensure they are notified.