# 500 Error being returned from Firebase Function

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is a followup question to ([Calling Firebase Function from Angular gives "bad request" error, but works fine called from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78176082/calling-firebase-function-from-angular-gives-bad-request-error-but-works-fine/78176095#78176095)) just for history purposes.

I had written a Firebase Function that I mistakenly wrote as an HTTP call instead of a callable function. I attempted to rewrite the function, but I'm still a little confused about syntax. The function I wrote is returning a 500 error. Can anyone please help me understand the correct approach and help me to fix this function?

The concept is simple. I have a collection named "quizzes" that contains quiz documents, and I want to return a given quiz doc by its doc.id. Here is the function code:

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and triggers.
const { logger } = require("firebase-functions");
const { onRequest } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const { cors } = require("cors")({ origin: true });

// Dependencies for callable functions.
const { onCall, HttpsError } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const { initializeApp, applicationDefault, cert } = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { getFirestore, Timestamp, FieldValue, Filter } = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

initializeApp();

const db = getFirestore();

exports.getQuizById = onCall(async (request, response) => {
    const quizId = request.queryid;

    if (!quizId) {
        throw new HttpsError("invalid-argument", "The function must be called " +
            "with one arguments \"id\" containing the id of the quiz to retrieve.");
    }

    try {
        const quizDocref = db.collection("quizzes").doc(quizId);
        const quizDoc = await quizDocref.get();

        // If there is no document with the given ID, return 404
        if (!quizDoc.exists) {
            throw new HttpsError("invalid-id", "The id " + quizId + " did not match any existing documents. Verify the id on the server or emulator and try again.");
        }

        // If the document exists, return the data from the document
        return quizDoc.data();

    } catch (error) {
        // If there is an error, log the error and return 500
        throw new HttpsError("server-error", "Error: " + error);
    }
});
```

I am calling this Function from the client side via:

```
import { Functions, httpsCallable } from '@angular/fire/functions';

  private functions: Functions = inject(Functions);

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    // get the id fdrom the url
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    const getQuizById = httpsCallable(this.functions, 'getQuizById');

    getQuizById({ id: 'ef8GwUuHt8X4XQJBIgZf' })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  }
```

ERROR MSG from the Firebase logger:

```
Error: Process exited with code 16
    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:92:22)
    at process.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at process.emit (node:domain:488:12)
    at process.exit (node:internal/process/per_thread:192:15)
    at sendCrashResponse (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/logger.js:44:9)
    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:84:44)
    at process.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at process.emit (node:domain:488:12)
    at process._fatalException (node:internal/process/execution:178:25)
```

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message (and stack trace) coming from the GCP Logs Explorer when the 500 error occurs?

Comment: BTW: `onCall()` does not have a `response` parameter.  It only has a `request` paremeter.

Comment: error msg is too long for comment, so I'll add it to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `request` object passed to the function is more complex than what you're expecting.  It contains a whole lot more than the payload sent by the client.  As stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function):

> The request parameter contains data passed from the client app as well as additional context like authentication state.

Use the [API documentation for CallableRequest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.https.callablerequest) to find out everything in it. The payload sent by the client is in the `data` property.  If your client is sending like this:

```
    const getQuizById = httpsCallable(this.functions, 'getQuizById');
    getQuizById({ id: 'ef8GwUuHt8X4XQJBIgZf' })
```

Then your function will need to receive it like this:

```
    const quizId = request.data.id;
```

Also note that there is no `response` object passed to the function.  You should remove it from your code.  The response is determined by the value you return from the function - you have no other control over it.