# firebase serve: From a locally served app, call locally served functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

> How can I properly simulate a cloud function locally so that it has all data as when being invoked on firebase servers? (e.g. the `context.auth`)

I am serving my project with `firebase serve`, it runs ok on `http://localhost:5000/`, however, my cloud functions are being called from `https://us-central1-<my-app>.cloudfunctions.net/getUser`. (The function is not even deployed.)

To avoid XY problem, I am trying to debug my function, but calling it from **firebase shell** results in `context.auth` being undefined, same when calling via **postman** from `http://localhost:5000/<my-app>/us-central1/getUser`.

This is my `./functions/src/index.ts` file

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import admin from 'firebase-admin'
import { inspect } from 'util'

admin.initializeApp()

export const getUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.debug('== getUser called =========================================')
  console.log('getUser', inspect(data), inspect(context.auth))
  return admin.database().ref('userRights/admin').child(context.auth.uid).once('value', snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.val())
    if (snapshot.val() === true) {
      return 'OK'
      // return {status: 'OK'}
    } else {
      return 'NOK'
      // return {status: 'error', code: 401, message: 'Unauthorized'}
    }
  })
})
```

file `./firebase.functions.ts`

```
import { functions } from '~/firebase'
export const getUser = functions.httpsCallable('getUser')
```

Consumer `./src/pages/AdminPanel/index.tsx`

```
import { getUser } from '~/firebase.functions'
//...
getUser({myDataX: 'asd'}).then(response => console.debug('response', response))
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue here. How did you get around that? Thanks.

Comment: @cbdev420 AFAIR I didn't. I just used exhaustive `console` statements (as above) and the logs in firebase console...

Comment: This worked for me: For locally you must call (after firebase.initializeApp):
`firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5000')` [source. It's on the 2nd answer to the question on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884534/how-to-test-functions-https-oncall-firebase-cloud-functions-locally)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE - April/2021**

As of April/2021, method `useFunctionsEmulator` has been deprecated. It is suggested to use method `useEmulator(host, port)` instead.

---

**Original post:**

By default, `firebase serve` sends queries to CLOUD function instead of localhost, but it is possible to change it to to point to localhost.

@gregbkr found a workaround for that at this [github](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/395#issuecomment-504913911) thread.

You basically add this after firebase initialization script (firebase/init.js) in html head.

```
<script>
   firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator("http://localhost:5001");
</script>
```

**Make sure to REMOVE it when deploying to SERVER**

Answer (score 5):

There is currently no support for local testing of callable functions like this.  The team is working on a way for you to specify the URL endpoint of a callable function so that you can redirect it to a different location for testing.

Comment: Bummer!  It's not just testing. This would be helpful while developing locally.

Comment: Why not have *firebase serve* configure the CORS to allow localhost when developing?  It fails with... 

  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson, isn't there a way to specify the endpoint for ALL functions like in `firebase.initializeApp`? Thanks!

Comment: Has anyone tried redirecting requests to localhost using `hosts` file?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a workaround.
using fiddlers AutoResponder to redirect the function call to the local served function.

**step 1**

copy the target url of the function from the client

[image: step 1]

**step 2**

copy the local served function url

[image]

**step 3**

active the auto respoder and use the following rules
(the second rule is also importent to allow all outher requests

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me, thank you @GorvGoyl!

```
script src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script
```