# Testing firebase function locally: How to point android app to the locally running callable functions?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I know I can start my firebase cloud functions locally by running below command.

```
firebase serve --only functions
```

But, is there any way I can point my android client app to the locally running functions when calling functions with android firebase SDK, so that I can test the real app before deploying the functions to firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the endpoint of a callable function using the client SDK is not currently supported.  The team is aware that developers would like to do this, but it never hurts to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to help the team gauge the amount of demand for this feature.

In the meantime, you have [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884534/how-to-test-functions-https-oncall-firebase-cloud-functions-locally) of invoking your callable locally, but not through the client SDK.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just using `HTTPS` endpoints

Yes, use your server added and url, if your on your local network, thats the IP address of your computer running the local server - note don't forget to include the port too, e.g:

```
192.168.0.100:5000/endpointName
```

With regards to database triggers and `onCall()` functions (rather than `HTTPS`) I don't think they would work - however I don't know for sure.

also deploying to `firebase` can be a time consuming process using:

`firebase deploy`

or sometimes even

`firebase deploy --only functions`

However the following example would only deploy one function that you can specify, which is significantly quicker in completing.

`firebase deploy --only functions:endpointName`

I Hope this helps!

Comment: The question is asking about redirecting callable functions via the Firebase client SDK, which is not currently supported.  What you're describing here is not realy relevant, unfortunately.