# How to test an onCall function as an authenticated user in the functions:shell

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I want to test an onCall function via `firebase functions:shell` as an authenticated usr

I’ve tried many of the combinations of calls from https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#invoke_https_functions
As well as downloading and setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var

My function looks like this:

```
exports.sendMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => { 
    if (!context.auth) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called while authenticated.');
    }
    // Other logic

}
```

It works fine once deployed and hit from my ios app, but i can’t get it running in the shell.

The following command will actually hit the function:

`sendMessage.post({headers: {'content-type' : 'application/json'},body: JSON.stringify({data: {'messageId':'test'} }) })`

and returns

`RESPONSE RECEIVED FROM FUNCTION: 400, {“error”:{“status”:“FAILED_PRECONDITION”,“message”:“The function must be called while authenticated.“}}`

Which is correct but I want an authenticated user now. When I try to add auth like the docs recommend:

`sendMessage('data', {auth:{uid:'USERUID'}}).post({headers: {'content-type' : 'application/json'},body: JSON.stringify({data: {'messageId':'test'} }) })`

I end up getting `ERROR SENDING REQUEST: Error: no auth mechanism defined`

If I try following the Authorization headers on this page https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference like so:

`sendMessage.post({headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer USERUID', 'content-type' : 'application/json'},body: JSON.stringify({data: {'messageId':'test'} }) })`

I get back:

RESPONSE RECEIVED FROM FUNCTION: 401, {"error":{"status":"UNAUTHENTICATED","message":"Unauthenticated"}}

How do you send the request as an authenticated user?

**Related Links**
[How to test `functions.https.onCall` firebase cloud functions locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884534/how-to-test-functions-https-oncall-firebase-cloud-functions-locally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, the Authorization header requires an authentication id *token*, not a user id.  You'll have to generate a token somehow and pass that to the function.  The callable function will then validate that token and provide the user id to the function via `context.auth`.

It looks like you can use the [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/) to get one of these tokens.  Or you can generate one in a client app that uses Firebase Auth client libraries, log it and copy its value, and use it until it expires (1 hour).

Comment: Nice, very good thing. Could you write an example, in firebase shell,  of call of a 'callable' with data structure for authentication ? i.e. second parameter of a callable. I cannot find any example anywhere.... :(

Comment: Would love to see an example of authentication for testing callable functions, I find the docs a little light around that :)