# use onCall functions with `firebase functions:shell` as an authenticated user

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Is there really no way to test firebase onCall functions as a logged in user via the shell? I get that you can use that google api curl command to quickly get a token as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52283028/2066855), but how do I call that upon a prompt in the shell then inject it into my call?

I don't get it, I cannot use postman anymore since they're onCall functions not HTTPS, so how do I actually test these things? Postman used to have a space to add it as a pre-call.

So far the only way I can get this to work is testing it live in the app, which is not the ideal development flow.

So how do I actually use the token curl command with the `firebase functions:shell`, I guess I could do some ridiculous keymapping but is that really what people are doing to test onCall functions in the shell as a logged in user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think this is a missing feature of the Firebase CLI, you should file a feature request on its [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools).

Instead of waiting for that to happen, it's probably just easier to use the [emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) to invoke the function locally exactly as you would as if it were deployed.  You can either test from your application using whatever test harness you normally use, or you can invoke the function with postman or curl using the [callable protocol spec](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) to construct the HTTP request and understand the response. (onCall functions are basically onRequest functions with a lot of implementation details handled automatically by the SDK and tools, but you're free to implement all that yourself as needed.) The spec says that you provide user credentials using the `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header.